# Как установить setAutoCancel(true) на addAction()?

Tags: java, android

Я сформировал `Notification` и установил setAutoCancel(true) и когда нажимаю на `Notification` он исчезает как положено.

Но у меня прикреплено 2 кнопки `addAction()` и когда я нажимаю на них то `Notification` не исчезает...

Можно ли как то поставить `setAutoCancel(true)` на кнопки? Чтоб после нажатия на них `Notification` удалялся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При нажатии на кнопку единственное что происходит - это отправляется связанный с ней PendginIntent.

Таким образом вы можете по нажатию на кнопку уведомления скрыть его лишь там, где вы принимаете Intent, запущенный кнопкой. Т.е. там вам надо через NotificationManager убрать уведомление

Comment: Я так и думал... Значит если я устанавливаю `id` для `Notification`  `0` вот так mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification); то удалять его я должен `mNotificationManager.cansel(0)` так? Просто я так сделал и не получилось... Нужно разбираться значит

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, да, принцип таков